# Evernote iOS Cloud SDK- Error in downloading EDAMResource data

Tags: ios, iphone, evernote

I have migrated from the IOS evernote sdks Migration_from_SDK_1_x.md  to evernote-cloud-sdk-ios to support the 64 bit architecture for our Daily Notes app.

I have followed the procedure mentioned in the guide(https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/blob/master/Migration_from_SDK_1_x.md) to migrate.

After migrating everything is working fine except the download of resource data.

When I am trying to download the attachments(images) using ENNoteStoreClient class's getResourceDataWithGuid: API, we get the following error all the time.

Error Domain=ENErrorDomain Code=1 "Missing result: getResourceData failed: unknown result" UserInfo=0x16b40490 {NSLocalizedDescription=Missing result: getResourceData failed: unknown result}

Steps to Reproduce

1. Create a note in the Evernote.
2. Attach a image to that note.
3. And try to download the resource..

Below is the code snippet for getting the EDAMNote and then getting the EDAMResource from it .

```
ENNoteStoreClient *noteStore=[ENSession sharedSession].primaryNoteStore;

    EDAMSyncChunkFilter *filter=[[EDAMSyncChunkFilter alloc]init];
    filter.includeNotes = @YES;
    filter.includeNoteResources = @YES;
    filter.includeNoteAttributes = @YES;
    filter.includeNotebooks = @YES;
    filter.includeTags = @YES;
    filter.includeSearches = @NO;
    filter.includeResources = @NO;
    filter.includeLinkedNotebooks = @NO;
    filter.includeExpunged = [NSNumber numberWithBool:!fullSunc];
    filter.includeNoteApplicationDataFullMap = @YES;
    filter.includeResourceApplicationDataFullMap = @NO;
    filter.includeNoteResourceApplicationDataFullMap = @YES;
    filter.requireNoteContentClass = nil;
    [noteStore getFilteredSyncChunkAfterUSN:currentUSN
                                 maxEntries:255
                                     filter:filter
                                    success:^(EDAMSyncChunk *syncChunk)
     {
         completionHandler(syncChunk,nil);
     }
                                    failure:^(NSError *error)
     {
         completionHandler(nil,error);
     }];
}

//I then extract the required EDAMNote from the syncChunk.


5. if I try to download the resource associated with this EDAMNote using “getResourceDataWithGuid:” API, it always  returns the error. This was working fine in earlier version. Here is the code snippet.

EDAMResource *resource = self.evernoteResource;
ENNoteStoreClient *noteStore = [ENSession sharedSession].primaryNoteStore;

[noteStore getResourceDataWithGuid:resource.guid success:^(NSData *data)
     {


     } failure:^(NSError *error)
     {

     }];
}
```

Error Domain=ENErrorDomain Code=1 "Missing result: getResourceData failed: unknown result" UserInfo=0x16b40490 {NSLocalizedDescription=Missing result: getResourceData failed: unknown result}

I have also observed the following log in the console put up by the SDK before getting this error. 
    Skipping field: due to type mismatch (received:11).

I have tried this procedure in the sample app and observed the same behaviour.

Anybody faced this issue?

Comment: the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243353/unable-to-download-the-note-attachmet-using-evernote-ios-sdk/27564429#27564429

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in latest update to the SDK.  See this issue on Github: https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/issues/73